# I get the error, list indices must be integers, do not know why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in inpt:
    for j in inpt[i]:
        print j,
```

I want to access a 2D array, for each array i in inpt, I want to print each number j in the array i. I do not have any formal background in python and also I could not already find a solution on the internet.

Comment: "print each number `j` in the array `i`" - as you said, `i` is an array, so loop using `for j in i` and not `for j in inpt[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `for` loops are [*foreach* loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), in that you get the actual elements from the list and not an index. You are trying to use those elements as indices to `inpt` again.

Loop over `i`, not `inpt[i]`, to get the matrix values:

```
for i in inpt:
    for j in i:
        print j,
```

I'd rename `i` to `row` to make this clearer:

```
for row in inpt:
    for j in row:
        print j,
```